# Is it possible to share access to dev version of a script deployed as a Web App?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on a GAS deployed as a Web App.
I can share the script and let others edit it, but I can't find a way to let them test the web app.

The link from "Test web app for your latest code." is available only to the owner of the script.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: If you want your script to be able to get the project version that it is running within then please go "star" @Edo 's corresponding [feature request (#1369)](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1369).  Your star equals a vote for this feature.  (The request is in the official Apps-Script issue tracker, [according](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing-features) to the official Google Apps Script Support page.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE:
Looks like this is available now - via [Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/release_notes) "If a script is shared with editors other than its owner and published as a web app, those other editors can now update the app's version and access its development URL (which ends in /dev)."

...
OLD WORKAROUND:
You could connect another script file into your main one as a workaround.  In the second script, import the main one as a [library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries) in Dev mode.  When you save, publish and share the exec link of the second it'll be like sharing the dev link.

Master script

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var btn = app.createButton('Click').setId('btn');
  var box = app.createTextBox().setId('box').setName('box').setText('hello');

  var handler1 = app.createClientHandler().forEventSource().setEnabled(false);
  var handler2 = app.createServerHandler('change').addCallbackElement(box);
  btn.addClickHandler(handler1).addClickHandler(handler2);

  app.add(btn).add(box);
  return app;
}

function change(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var box = e.parameter.box;
  app.getElementById('btn').setText(box).setEnabled(true);
  return app;
}
```

Second script (after importing Master script as a library and naming the identifier as 'master')

```
function doGet() {
  var app = master.doGet();
  return app;
}
```

Comment: This is very smart!  Did you try it before or did you imagine this because of the question?

Comment: Yeah I have a few apps setup like this, but I'm not clear on when exactly we need to reference other Master functions besides doGet() in the second script.  The `change()` doesn't need referenced in the second in this case, but I have apps that do need to reference other functions.  Don't know the circumstances why.  Maybe I'll post a separate question for this if no one comments on it as it is more of a library question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the supported way to deploy Google app script as a web service: create new versions and publish them, then all editors can access the app by its deployment URL(s). This allows all editors to test the latest *published* version, but not the latest *edited* version.

The cons of this approach:

- Two steps required for every re-publication. (`Manage Versions / Create`, then `Deploy`.)
- Your app must be publicly accessible.

The pros:

- Once published as a web app, the URL does not change, so everyone sees the latest copy by simply reloading.
- You can easily republish previous versions for side-by-side comparison testing.

Answer (score -1):

It is not currently possible to share that.